# Should I break down codes into as many functions as possible?

Tags: performance, oop, class, function, design-patterns

Lets say I have a function that logs in a user in pseudo code

```
def login():
    # find user in db
    # check if user exists
    # check password
    # login user
```

Should each action be its own function? or should all the code just stay in there?

Edit: I ask this because I usually just put all my code in one function, but a friend of mine puts everything he needs to do in multiple functions and then fills in the blanks on functions he wrote down

ex. he would write this:

```
def login():
    findUser()
    checkUser()
    checkPass()
    userLoggedin()
```

he would then create those functions and fill them in.

Comment: A common opinion is that a function should do *one and only one* thing.  I've also heard a function shouldn't be more than about a page or so on the screen, but I'm not sure if I really agree with that.

Comment: Responding to your `performance` tag, i shouldn't expect noticable performance impact in breaking up code in logical functions, with modern compilers and optimizations, like inlining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice is:

Break it into meaningful, re-usable functions. This will be most useful to maintain when your code base grows.

```
# find user in db         => re-usable
# check if user exists    => No. If you find it, it exists. So you don't need that.
                             If you don't find it, it does not. So both should be the same.
# check password          => re-usable
# login user              => re-usable
```

*Note: There is a WWDC 2012 session video entitled:*

**Basics+Habits: Building Your Software Projects To Last**

*that you could watch. The targeted audience is mainly MAC developers, but many of their advices applies to other object-oriented languages as well. You will need a free MAC developer account to access it.*

Comment: +1 Yeah and group into logical concerns for easy re-use but also to find common methods when the code base grows me thinks.

Comment: Checking the password should probably be part of finding the user in the database for security and to minimize db round trips. The result of not finding a user, and a password mismatch should be the same. Steps would be 1. check if username and password combination exists, step 2 login or return error.

Comment: This is indeed relevant. Thanks. I'll add it.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple Yes. But what if you just want to know if some user exists?

Comment: But if you are using say LINQ, and the OP mentiones nothing about language, then getting the user will get you an object with the password etc so you don't have another DB hit.

Comment: I just used logging in a user as an example, I'm more concerned about the style of how people code. Whether they write down a bunch of functions they haven't created yet and then fill them in or just go straight to coding.

Comment: Normalization isn't always ideal. Depending on the project, I might keep GetUser which returns a full user object isolated to an admin project, whereas getting a user object from a username and password would be available to the normal website.

Comment: @Wesley Agreed, but one thing this demonstrates is there is no solid rule, and context matters.

Comment: There is no clear-cut answer. This answer is to be fitted to the project. Optimizations (like minimizing db fetches, or improving fps for graphic display) are valid reasons to stray away from the obvious function split.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say YES and they should be split into separate projects speaking from a Visual Studio point of view.

Find User - Data Repository

Check User exists - Probably a Model or Business Layer

Check Password, model or business layer

Login - Business layer

The aim here is to group code into logical concerns.